# How to interpret Glimmer scores?

Tags: interpretation, odds-ratio, bioinformatics

I am trying to find orfs with Glimmer. At the end, Glimmer gives me a .predict file with the orfs and a corresponding raw score.

When I look at the documentation, it says about the score, "This is 100 times the per-base log-odds ratio of the in-frame coding ICM score to the independent (i.e., non-coding) model score. It gives a rough quantification to how well an orf scores that can be compared between any two orfs." You can look here for the documentation-

https://ccb.jhu.edu/software/glimmer/glim302notes.pdf

But what does the score really mean in an absolute manner? How do I realize for an orf, if the score is significant or not?